# Where can I find a catalog for stars within 450 light-years of Earth?

Tags: star

Where can I find a catalog for stars within 450 light-years of Earth? I'd prefer one that has approximated masses as well.

Comment: I remember reading that there's 14,000 stars within 100 light years.   Within 450 light years, 91 times the area, you could be looking at a million or so stars.   Do you actually want a catalog with a million entries, cause that would be pretty cumbersome.

Comment: I like to mention NOMAD as often as possible, so here you go: http://www.usno.navy.mil/USNO/astrometry/optical-IR-prod/nomad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Hipparcos catalogue (use the revision by [van Leeuwen 2007](http://cdsarc.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/Cat?I/311)) contains trigonometric parallaxes and is complete down to about 9th magnitude.

What this means is that you will have a complete set of measurements for F-type main sequence stars and hotter, and all giant stars within 450 light years. However, the sample will not be complete for G dwarfs or cooler, since these are fainter than 9th magnitude at 450 light years.

The catalogue does not contain mass, since mass is not a measurable quantity for single stars. If you want masses you will have to use relationships between absolute magnitude and mass for main sequence stars (e.g. [Kroupa 2007](http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9701213)), but note that these depend on metallicity and a little bit on stellar age. Masses are extremely difficult to estimate for giants.

If you can wait a couple of years, the Gaia mission will report parallax distances for all stars to magnitudes of 19 or 20. This will be almost complete at 450 light years, even for M dwarfs.